# Check if text is in a string

Tags: javascript

I want to check is some text is in a string for instance i have a string

```
str = "car, bycicle, bus"
```

and I have another string

```
str2 = "car"
```

I want to check if str2 is in str.

I am a newbie in javascript so please bear with me :)

Regards

Comment: A nice reference on javascript `String` methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
if(str.indexOf(str2) >= 0) {
   ...
}
```

Or if you want to go the regex route:

```
if(new RegExp(str2).test(str)) {
  ...
}
```

However you may face issues with escaping (metacharacters) in the latter, so the first route is easier.

Comment: This should work perfectly.  `indexOf` returns the index of the beginning of `str2` in `str`.  returns -1 if it isn't in the array.

Comment: I like to use the != -1 variant. ----  if(str.indexOf(str2) != -1) {}

Answer (score 10):

**ES5**

```
if(str.indexOf(str2) >= 0) {
   ...
}
```

**ES6**

```
if (str.includes(str2)) {

}
```

Answer (score 4):

`str.lastIndexOf(str2) >= 0;` this should work. untested though.

```js
let str = "car, bycicle, bus";
let str2 = "car";
console.log(str.lastIndexOf(str2) >= 0);
```

Comment: why use `lastIndexOf` instead of just `indexOf`?

Comment: Just force of habit, i've gotten burned in the past using indexOf...lastIndexOf works the same as far as I know when there is only one instance of the string being looked for.

Comment: Interesting. What circumstances would case `indexOf` to cause trouble?

Comment: If you are looking for more than one way to skin this cat you could `var items = str.split(",")` into an array then iterate through the array items checking for items[i] == str2....

Comment: @Hughes, Not at all saying my way is right, and not something I've done in practice in a long time but, `var x = ',,'` `x.indexOf(x) == 0` `x.lastIndexOf(x) == 1`, you'd get two different results, and depending on the logic down the line you could have some issues.

Answer (score 4):

Use the builtin `.includes()` string method to check for the existence of sub-string.
It return boolean which indicates if the sub-string included or not.

```
const string = "hello world";
const subString = "world";

console.log(string.includes(subString));

if(string.includes(subString)){
   // SOME CODE
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use this :

```
var s = "foo";
alert(s.indexOf("oo") > -1);
```

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer except that you use `>` instead of `>=`?

Comment: Ram,

Both are the same!! If you will see  conditions then both are indicating the same that whatever the value you get using "indexOf" function should be greater than or equal 0.

Comment: Both are the same that's what I meant. Please don't add a duplicate answer to the question instead upvote the existing answer if desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
'a nice string'.includes('nice')
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will tell you if the substring is in the string and how many times.

```js
 const textInString = (wordToFind, wholeText) => {
    const text = new RegExp(wordToFind, 'g');
    const occurence = wholeText.match(text) ?? [];
    return [occurence.length > 0, occurence.length]
 }
 
 console.log(textInString("is", "This cow jumped over this moon"))
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to check substring in a string you can use `indexOf` but if you want to check if the word is in the string or not, the other answers might not work correctly for example:

```
str = "carpet, bycicle, bus"
str2 = "car"
What you want car word is found not car in carpet
if(str.indexOf(str2) >= 0) {
  // Still true here
}
// OR 
if(new RegExp(str2).test(str)) {
  // Still true here 
}
```

So you can improve the regex a bit to make it work

```
str = "carpet, bycicle, bus"
str1 = "car, bycicle, bus"
stringCheck = "car"
// This will false
if(new RegExp(`\b${stringCheck}\b`).test(str)) {
  
}
// This will true
if(new RegExp(`\b${stringCheck}\b`,"g").test(str1)) {
  
}
```