# Check if a string has a certain piece of text

Tags: javascript, string

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Check if text is in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614424/check-if-text-is-in-a-string)
>   [JavaScript: string contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/javascript-string-contains)

I'm trying to check if a string I import into my application has a certain piece of text. I know how to do this with jQuery, but how do I do it with straight up JavaScript?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring

Comment: Here a benchmark for the most common ways to check if a string is in a string: http://jsben.ch/#/o6KmH

Answer (score 470, accepted):

Here you go: **ES5**

```
var test = 'Hello World';
if( test.indexOf('World') >= 0){
  // Found world
}
```

With **ES6** best way would be to use `includes` function to test if the string contains the looking work.

```
const test = 'Hello World';
if (test.includes('World')) { 
  // Found world
}
```

Comment: What if the string starts with "World"? The operator should probably be `>= 0`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, and >=0 value is a match

Comment: I like !== -1 better

Comment: I like `if (~test.indexOf('World'))` better

Comment: When to use ES6?

Comment: @KhomNazid https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6

Comment: test.includes('World') works best for me.