# How to check whether a string contains a substring in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Usually I would expect a `str.includes()` method, but there doesn't seem to be one in TypeScript.

Comment: Check this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629728/check-if-a-string-has-a-certain-piece-of-text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629728/check-if-a-string-has-a-certain-piece-of-text)

Comment: The first variant: 
let test = 'Hello World';
if(test.indexOf('World') >= 0){
  // Found world
}
helped. Thank you